# How to do a "docker-compose" in a "docker machine"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to test something and I need to create containers in each `docker machines` I have. So on my local host I have a lot of containers and 2 machines (`vbox-t` and `vbox-t2`).

I can't find in documentation how to connect in a machine and create containers inside.
Someone can help me ?

[EDIT] I have found this on Docker documentation:

> Use Machine to run Docker containers To run a Docker container, you:
>
> create a new (or start an existing) Docker virtual machine
>   switch your
>   environment to your new VM
>   use the docker client to create, load, and
>   manage containers
>    Once you create a machine, you can reuse it as often
>   as you like. Like any VirtualBox VM, it maintains its configuration
>   between uses.
>
> The examples here show how to create and start a machine, run Docker
>   commands, and work with containers.

But how to switch my environment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure our Docker client talks to the Docker engine in your vbox-t machine you need to run

```
eval $(docker-machine env vbox-t)
```

To restore just use:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env -u)"
```

This will remove the DOCKER_* variables so your docker commands will connect to your local env.

Comment: So with this I go inside `vbox-t` ? If it's the case how can I return to the local engine after ?

Comment: Thank you it's a great answer now !